Get Multiple Sheets by Name in Google Sheets
I would like to have this function apply to multiple sheets:
As you can see I am getting sheet name 2024, I would like to update this as needed from example, 2022,2023,2024,2025,2026 and so on.  I am sure this is super easy but I am very new to google sheet coding.  This is a modified snippet of this script: https://gist.github.com/mikebranski/285b60aa5ec3da8638e5
  var required_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2024");
  var range = required_sheet.getDataRange();

  // Then, if there are any header rows, offset our range to remove them from
  // it; otherwise, they will end up being sorted as well.
  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    // Setting the second parameter of offset() to 0 to prevents it from
    // shifting any columns. Note that row headers wouldn't make much
    // sense here, but this is where you would modify it if you
    // wanted support for those as well.
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }

  // Perform the actual sort.
  range.sort([ {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX_1,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  },
  {column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX_2,
    ascending: ASCENDING} ]);
}


Related question: How can I use the same script for multiple sheets on a spreadsheet

I think the question is slightly different from the proposed duplicates because sheet names form a sequence that can be matched with a regex. It also asks how to sort a sheet, while (1) is about hiding rows and (2) is about dependent dropdowns.

Here's how to sort sheets whose names matches the regular expression ^(20\d\d)$ by columns A:B when one of those columns is manually edited:
'use strict';

/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window.');
  autoSortSheet_(e);
}

/**
* Sorts the active sheet by one or more columns when a columnsToWatch is
* edited manually, only on sheetsToWatch and excluding sheetsToExclude.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function autoSortSheet_(e) {
  // version 1.4, written by --Hyde, 23 September 2024
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/79012570/13045193
  try {
    const parameters = [

      ////////////////////////////////
      // [START modifiable parameters]
      {
        sheetsToWatch: /^(20\d\d)$/i,
        sheetsToExclude: undefined,
        columnsToWatch: [1, 2,], // columns A:B
        sortBy: [
          { column: 1, ascending: true },  // column A
          { column: 2, ascending: true },  // column B
        ],
      },
      // [END modifiable parameters]
      ////////////////////////////////

    ];
    let sheet, sheetName;
    const settings = parameters.find(p =>
      (!p.columnsToWatch.length || p.columnsToWatch.includes(e.range.columnStart))
      && (sheetName = sheetName || (sheet = sheet || e.range.getSheet()).getName()).match(p.sheetsToWatch)
      && (!p.sheetsToExclude || !sheetName.match(p.sheetsToExclude))
    );
    if (!settings) return;
    settings.sortBy.reverse().forEach(spec => sheet.sort(spec.column, spec.ascending));
    e.source.toast('The sheet was sorted.');
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(`${error.message} ${error.stack}`, 'Error in simple trigger', 30);
    throw error;
  }
}

The code observes these onEdit(e) best practices.
To choose the number of header rows to leave unsorted, choose View > Freeze > Rows.

I was able to get this to work and here is the code.  I got the idea from Apply to Specific Tabs within a Sheet


function autoSort(sheet) {
  //var required_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2024");
  //var range = required_sheet.getDataRange();
  // Get the entire set of data for this sheet.
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_name = ['2022','2023', '2024'];
  for (s=0; s<sheet_name.length; s++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name[s]);
    //get range
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();

      // Then, if there are any header rows, offset our range to remove them from
  // it; otherwise, they will end up being sorted as well.
  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    // Setting the second parameter of offset() to 0 to prevents it from
    // shifting any columns. Note that row headers wouldn't make much
    // sense here, but this is where you would modify it if you
    // wanted support for those as well.
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }

  // Perform the actual sort.
  range.sort([ {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX_1,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  },
  {column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX_2,
    ascending: ASCENDING} ]);
    }
}




Hmm... there should be no need to sort sheets other than the one that was edited, and even that sheet should only be sorted when one of the sort key columns changed (because sorting only modifies the order of rows when sort keys change.) If autoSort() is run every time any edit takes place, there will be many wasted CPU cycles, and spreadsheet performance will consequently suffer. Also see onEdit(e) best practices.
